# Proper way to compare strings and integers?

Tags: vb.net

I suspect there is something wrong in my application, specifically in a part where I have to compare a couple strings and a couple integers.

I do something like this:

```
If myString = myOtherString Then
  do something
End If
```

And the same thing for integers.

However, for some reason, it is not returning true... also, I heard somewhere there were more proper ways to compare strings and integers. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you comparing a strings to strings & integers to integers... or strings to integers?

Comment: Can you show us some sample input, compared with the actual and expected output?

Comment: More specifically, what are the values of myString and myOtherString? Remember that if the case is different they will not be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like anything is wrong with your code. I suspect there is something more, like the case of the string.

Comment: vb.net is natively case insensitive unless compare binary is forced.

Comment: @Joel: Option Compare Binary is the default setting, and has always been as far as I know.

Comment: @Cody Gray - not in any studio I've ever installed. 2005/2008/2010. I've had to force it in all of our projects.

Comment: @Cody Gray - actually I take that back. I have two machines that were configured with 2010 one opting for vb settings and one for c# settings. The c# machine has binary for vb. The vb machine has text. All the machines I've had previously were vb settings, so maybe my viewpoint is prejudicial.

Comment: @Joel: I set my primary development environment up with the VB profile settings as well. (It's my dirty little secret that VB is my favorite language.) It always defaults to Option Compare Binary. The documentation agrees with me. I'm not sure what you've seen before; that's very strange. The VB IDE is case-insensitive, but that isn't true by default for text comparisons. Option Compare Text is a performance penalty, too. Another good reason for it not to be the default.

Comment: I tell you what: My code was a horrible limbo, plain stupid. I am sorry, thank you for helping :(